# 0 Byte File Windows Contacts

Tags: windows, contacts

I have synced contacts from my blackberry to windows contacts on windows 7 and the transfer has created a number of files under the name of the person but they are 0 byte files. You cannot delete or do anything with these files as if you attempt any action it says "item not found, could not find this item, this is no longer located in C:\Users\User\Contacts. Verify the items location and try again. The file description just comes up as Amandaa(name of one of my contacts), Type: File, Size: 0 bytes.

Is there any way I can delete these files, correct problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting them via the command line interface?